Orthogonal trajectory to a pencil of conics
An orthogonal trajectory is a curve which intersects any curve of a given pencil of (planar) curves orthogonally.
A pencil of conics $λP(x,y)+Q(x,y)=0,λ∈ℝ$, where $P,Q$ are polynomials of degree $≤2$, what conditions must be satisfied to make its orthogonal curve family also consisting of conics?

Examples of Orthogonal trajectory that don't consist of conics
Orthogonal trajectory to the pencil $x^2 +λy^2=1$ is the family of curves $2 \log|x| - x^2 - y^2=\text{const}$

Orthogonal trajectory to the pencil $(x^2-1)+λ(y^2-1)=0$ is the family of curves $2\log|x y|- x^2 - y^2=\text{const}$


Examples of Orthogonal trajectory that consists of conics
For two circles, there exist a pencil of coaxal circles orthogonal to the pencil.

For ellipses with the same foci, there exist a pencil of confocal hyperbola orthogonal to the pencil.
For parabola with the same foci and direction, there exist a pencil of confocal parabola orthogonal to the pencil.

Parabolas $y=\alpha x^2$ and ellipses $x^2+2y^2=\alpha$

